# Monte Carlo simulated price and Black Scholes Price are giving a huge difference in my Matlab code

Tags: black-scholes, monte-carlo, finance-mathematics

I have written a script for  showing Monte Carlo Price for a increasing N. 
But comparing with BS results , This indicates a huge difference. Where is the error?

Function :

```
 function [cpay,ppay] = callput(S0,K,T,r,sigma,N)
%CALLPUT Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
phi=normrnd(0,sigma,[1,N]);
dT=T;
for i=1:N
    S(i)=S0*exp((r-.5*sigma.^2)*dT + sigma*sqrt(dT)*phi(i));
    C(i)= exp(-r*T)*max(S(i)-K, 0);
    P(i)=exp(-r*T)*max(K-S(i), 0);
end 
price1=sum(C)/N;
price2=sum(P)/N;
cpay=price1;
ppay=price2;
end
```

Main Script:

```
clc
clear all
% f=fopen('CPData.txt','w');
[BSCall, BSPut] = blsprice(5,5,.04,.5,.2)
fprintf('i\tMC-Call\tMC-Put\n');
for i=1:50

    [cpayoff,ppayoff]=callput(5,5,.5,.04,.2,i*1000);
    cp(i)=cpayoff;
    pp(i)=ppayoff;
    fprintf('%d\t%3.4f\t%3.4f\n',i*1000,cp(i),pp(i));

end
```

Results :

```
BSCall =

    0.3314


BSPut =

    0.2323

i       MC-Call MC-Put
1000    0.0894  0.0333
2000    0.0838  0.0344
3000    0.0842  0.0331
4000    0.0847  0.0335
5000    0.0852  0.0349
6000    0.0842  0.0330
7000    0.0865  0.0326
8000    0.0844  0.0348
9000    0.0862  0.0329
10000   0.0863  0.0340
11000   0.0859  0.0323
12000   0.0849  0.0346
13000   0.0852  0.0346
14000   0.0861  0.0342
15000   0.0863  0.0325
16000   0.0854  0.0338
17000   0.0839  0.0342
18000   0.0844  0.0340
19000   0.0861  0.0343
20000   0.0845  0.0338
21000   0.0836  0.0341
22000   0.0842  0.0340
23000   0.0853  0.0338
24000   0.0842  0.0341
25000   0.0844  0.0344
26000   0.0863  0.0329
27000   0.0846  0.0332
28000   0.0845  0.0335
29000   0.0852  0.0339
30000   0.0854  0.0334
31000   0.0849  0.0339
32000   0.0851  0.0337
33000   0.0846  0.0340
34000   0.0849  0.0334
35000   0.0850  0.0335
36000   0.0846  0.0339
37000   0.0855  0.0337
38000   0.0851  0.0335
39000   0.0849  0.0335
40000   0.0855  0.0330
41000   0.0853  0.0330
42000   0.0847  0.0337
43000   0.0849  0.0330
44000   0.0850  0.0343
45000   0.0850  0.0338
46000   0.0856  0.0337
47000   0.0846  0.0335
48000   0.0854  0.0337
49000   0.0851  0.0334
50000   0.0853  0.0336
```

Comment: Do you price strike 0 correctly ? This is the first check. Also what does normrnd function do exactly ? Seems weird you provide sigma inside and normalize again by sigma in your exponential.

Comment: Yes. I forget to note that this program is for European Option pricing only..

Comment: this is clear from code but you did not show result for strike 0.

Comment: How can I solve this ? Here : S0= 5; K=5,r=.04,sigma=.2,T=.5 ... How can I get the expected result ?

Comment: double check your formulas

Comment: I have checked it many times. Evereywhere I've found , it  is okay.  Is there any error with generating Phi values ?

Comment: You are not answering my question so i will let you dig a bit more

Comment: normd= generates a random number from the normal distribution ; here my Mean =0; SD= sigma.. And It is a built in function in Matlab.. I think you are well known about this.. I am normalising this , Because Phi is a random vbariable drawn from a normalised Normal Distribution

Comment: you have still not answered my first question that i asked 2 times already :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding this. Can you explain it little more?

Comment: there is nothing to explain. Read the first question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting this.

Comment: then i will let other people answer you. Obviously you are not willing to make minimal effort to read my first comment to you so i will not spend more time in this thread. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry , I was really unable to get your question. It's my fault, But not actually avoiding your qustion. Do you mean Strike price when 0? Then the results come call= 4.95(about) , Put =0. In BS call=5  put=0

Comment: I repeat It's my falut not to understand your question properly.

Comment: so your formula for S is wrong. Obviously you need to check better your formula.

Comment: Can you suggest, Please?

Comment: Also what does normrnd function do exactly ? Seems weird you provide sigma inside and normalize again by sigma in your exponential.//// Got it.. Thank you. I'm really sorry to take much understand this line .. But really helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the formula for S, the variable phi should be a normal standard variable, not with stdev sigma.